# function to add elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program that adds the elements of the same cardinality in two separate lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

list2 = [2,3,4]
```

Thus `list3` would be `[3,5,7]`

This is the code I have:

```
def add_list(lst1,lst2):
    sum_lst = []
    index = 0
    while (len(lst1)-1) >= index:
        sum_lst[index] == lst1[index] + lst2[index]
        index += 1
    return sum_lst
```

I get this error "index out of range" when I run it:

```
sum_lst[index] == lst1[index] + lst2[index]
```

How is it out of range considering that I stop the index before it reaches past the length of the list?

Comment: This way is way too un-pythonic. Please reconsider your implementation, although I'll hint it has something to do with both your left-hand side of the assignment as well as the assignment operator...

Answer (score 6):

```
sum_lst[index] == lst1[index] + lst2[index]
          ^1    ^2
```

2 main issues:

1. you initialize sum_lst as '[]` which means, YES, 0 IS out of index.
2. `==` is not the same as `=`. `==` is a boolean expression operation that asses equality whereas `=` is the assignment operator.

two fixes:

```
#replaces that one line
sum_lst.append(lst1[index]+lst2[index])
```

OR

```
#replaces the whole function
sum_lst = [x+y for x,y in zip(lst1,lst2)]
```

Comment: Correct as it may be, your novel fails to mention that any pythonista tumbles to the floor in white-hot agony before completely scanning through the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're running into your error message is because `sum_lst` doesn't yet have the indices you're looking for.

E.g. if you try

```
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list[0] = 1 # you'll get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Instead, try something like:

```
sum_lst.append(lst1[index] + lst2[index])
```

This'll add a new element to the end of the array

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line was already pointed out:

```
sum_lst[index] == lst1[index] + lst2[index]
```

In addition to this fix, I'm going to explain a few steps you could take to improve this code and similar code.

Instead of incrementing an index and using a `while` loop, it's common practice to use a `for` loop in Python.  We can use the `range` function to loop over all indexes.

Here's an improvement (note we fixed `append` and the `==` issue here):

```
def add_list(lst1, lst2):
    sum_lst = []
    for index in range(len(lst1)):
        sum_lst.append(lst1[index] + lst2[index])
    return sum_lst
```

But that still isn't idiomatic.

It would be even better to use the `enumerate` function to loop over items while retrieving their indices. Whenever you see something like `for i in range(len(lst1))` think `enumerate`.

```
def add_list(lst1, lst2):
    sum_lst = []
    for index, item1 in enumerate(lst1):
        sum_lst.append(item1 + lst2[index])
    return sum_lst
```

The only reason we need the index is because we're trying to loop over two lists at once.  Whenever you need to loop over multiple lists at the same time, you can use the `zip` function to zip iterables/lists together:

```
def add_list(lst1, lst2):
    sum_lst = []
    for item1, item2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
        sum_lst.append(item1 + item2)
    return sum_lst
```

This is nearly the best we could do.  There's just one more improvement we could make: use a list comprehension instead of a `for` loop:

```
def add_list(lst1, lst2):
    return [item1 + item2 for item1, item2 in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(list1,list2)]
[3, 5, 7]
```

I'd say the main problem with your code isn't the bug itself, it's that you're writing in a traditionally procedural pattern. Perhaps you used to do Java or C? Python is a multi-paradigm language, and supports functional programming. The main takeaway is that you should try to keep things immutable, so instead of creating empty lists and gradually populating them with content, try to create the resulting list on the fly. As in the example above. That way you won't be able produce indexing errors on either side of the assignment operator.

But, if you really want to know, your bug is two-fold:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[1] = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I.e. you can't append things to a list by assigning to a new element. You could do it this way instead:

```
a += [3]
```

Secondly you've used a comparison operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: thanks. what is wrong with my code though? i would like to know the mistake i'm making

Comment: Please **explain your answer**. A plain code snippet by itself is *rarely* helpful.

Comment: @JonasByström Can we continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94983/discussion-between-ethan-bierlein-and-jonas-bystrom)? I don't want to have this discussion get too out of hand in the comments.